# UIButton has to be tapped repeatedly before touchUpInside fires

Tags: ios4, uibutton

I have two UIButtons (start and dismiss), contained by a UIView, contained by an outer UIView.

There is nothing special about the buttons.

This is all done in a xib file.

For one of the buttons, it just works.

For the other, when the code is running (simulator or on the iPad doesn't matter), a touchUpInside message is sent to the corresponding controller only on about 10% of taps.  tap-tap-taptaptap-tap...tap-tapFIRE.  Sometimes tapping slowly and methodically works better.  Sometimes.

When it does finally fire, the message (dismissWindow:) is called/received/processed correctly.

The button has a referencing IBOutlet ("dismiss", although I've tried it both with and without one).
The button, the view and the parent view are all "User interaction enabled" and not hidden.
I've tried with the button both on the parent view, and on the subview.
I've tried with the action set to the view container, and to First Responder.
I've ensured that the button is in front.

Is there some urban legend about dodgy and/or finicky UIButtons on the iPhone/iPad?  Am I missing some setting someplace?

The other button on the view, Buttons in other xib files, or those created dynamically work as expected.  It is simply this one xib file and this one button.

.h

```
UIButton *dismiss;
...
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *dismiss;
```

.m

```
@synthesize    ..., dismiss, ...;
...
-(IBAction)dismissWindow:(id)sender {
    [[controller detailViewController] dismissWaitView:self];
    [self removeFromSuperview];
}
```

So I throw this out to the collective consciousness.  What can I try?

TIA,
rip

Comment: I've tried replacing the button with a navbar+barbuttonitem, and get the same behavior.  The button does not wish to be triggered until you've tapped it a couple of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, what I noticed was that the UIButton was of type "custom" and the text was "Done" and the style was "Done".  Changing any one of those was sufficient to make the button work as I expected it to.

I changed the text from "Done" to "Finished", and it suddenly started working.